# Handling an issue on using a state value after immediately after setState is called in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, setstate

I have a function "handleSelectChange" that sets the value of my html select input tag to the value the user choose. (values are one-day, one-week, one-month, one-year, meant for duration of subscriptions to a product)

After setting the state, in the same function, I tried to make use of the state value by pushing it to a database (firestore collection), alongside some other values (as a document key value field) immediately, using an if and else if statement to determine what to send depending on the input value from the select tag

One of the values is an "expiration date" so I use the state value to determine the expiration date value to push, hence the if and else if statements.

Like so:

```
    if (selectedValue === "One-day" ){
                const createdAt = new Date();
                await addDoc(subscriptionCollectionRef, { 
                    Subscription: selectedValue,
                    Date_created : createdAt,
                    Expiration_date: createdAt.setHours(createdAt.getHours() + 24)
                 });
            }

    

else if (selectedValue === "One-week" ){
        const createdAt = new Date();
        await addDoc(subscriptionCollectionRef, { 
            Subscription: selectedValue,
            Date_created : createdAt,
            Expiration_date: createdAt.setDate(createdAt.getDate() + 7)
         });
    }
```

....

To my dismay, it doesn't get sent, until I choose another value in the select input tag. (Selecting the same value again doesn't do anything at all).

So, I have to select a first input (like say "One-day"), and then another one (like say "One-week") before I can add the document (that is supposed to be from selecting from the first input "One-day") to the firestore collection.

I verify this from looking at the firestore collection (and refreshing, if need be) while selecting the input

I tried separating the part of the code that adds the document to a different function from the "handleSelectChange" function, then call the function inside the "handleSelectChange" function.

It did not work out. I know react doesnt update state immediately, but i dont know how to resolve this now.

Comment: If it's in the same function, you could just have your condition reliant on the arguments passed to the function rather than the state variable which most likely isn't set yet. A more elegant way might be to do it in a useEffect with the state variable as part of the dependency array.